# SQL to summarize data

Tags: php, mysql

I have table name student as below:

[image: student Table]

how to write Query to get like this:

[image: Out Put Query Table]

I searched so many examples but no use please any one help me for this code in mysql and php.

Code attempt:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT PCLASS FROM student GROUP BY PCLASS; ")or die(mysqli_error()); 

$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); 

$result2 = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN GEN = 'Male' THEN OID END) AS Males, COUNT(CASE WHEN GEN = 'Female' THEN OID END) AS Females, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM student where OID='{$_SESSION["OID"]}' ")or die(mysqli_error()); 
$row1 = $result2->fetch_assoc(); while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

CODE IMPROVED as below I am getting only one PCLASS, I am not getting All Classes.

MY IMPROVED CODE:

```
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT PCLASS, COUNT(CASE WHEN GEN = 'Male' THEN 1 END) AS Males,COUNT(CASE WHEN GEN = 'Female' THEN 1 END) AS Females,COUNT(*) AS Total FROM student GROUP BY PCLASS;")or die(mysqli_error());$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

PLEASE any one help me about this issue.... Thanking you in Advance

Comment: Research mysql pivot.

Comment: "any one write for this code in mysql and php.". Stack Overflow is *NOT* a code-writing service

Comment: MySQL has a `GROUP BY` clause. You need to research that!

Comment: thank you all. Ben i tried GROUP BY clause but i am not getting correct result.

Comment: "I was searched so many examples "...ok and what exactly did you try? What went wrong? Please show your best attempt at solving it. As mentioned, we're not really just here to do all the work for you, so please demonstrate to us that you made a serious attempt first. Then we'd be happy to assist in more detail. If you tried GROUP BY, then show us what you did, and what the result was. Maybe it only needs a small change in order to be correct.

Comment: I updated my question please check once. any suggestion about my issue. thank you all.

Comment: I use only Access db so CASE is not available. I would use IIf() instead. Otherwise, attempted syntax seems fine. Example output should also be producible with a CROSSTAB (PIVOT) SQL. Search that topic. Count shown for 5th does not agree with sample data - a minor typo.

Comment: finally I solved my problem after three days.... thank you all...

Comment: That's great. Please write it as an answer, below, then everyone can benefit, and you can get upvotes if people find it useful. That way, this site gets better for everyone - thanks :-)

Comment: @ADyson Its my plesure

Comment: No you must add it to the **answers** section, below this. Your answer should not be part of your question, they are separate! :-)

Comment: @Adyson Ok... Done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Below code worked for me:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"select `PCLASS`, COUNT(SID) as Total, sum(IF(`GEN` = 'Female',1,0)) as Females,sum(IF(`GEN` = 'Male',1,0)) as Males FROM student where OID='{$_SESSION["OID"]}' GROUP BY `PCLASS`");
```